# Generating Signed APK is successful but google play says it isn't signed

Tags: android, apk

I am signing an apk with a keystore I just generated. Gradle confirms that a signed apk is generated. There are no gradle errors at all!

However when I upload it to the google play store, I am told that it is not signed. I am not sure how to debug this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 3):

Enable the V1 and V2 signature schemes before generate apk on last dialog.

Comment: Thanks! I missed the v1 checkbox. Realized that right before I saw your answer!